# Can every bilinear map be represented as $B(x, y) = A(x)y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B(x, y) : X \times Y \to Z$ be a bilinear map on finite-dimensional vector spaces. Is it true that every such map admits a unique representation $A(x)y$ where $A : X \to (Y \to Z)$ is a linear map and $A(x)$ is a linear operator?

Comment: Do you mean that $B(x,\cdot)$ is a linear map and $B(ax+by,\cdot)=aB(x,\cdot)+bB(y,\cdot)$? Yes, that much is sorta trivial from the definition (though there may be some conjugates involved if the base field is complex depending on your convention for what "bilinear" means). The more interesting question is going the other way, which is called the Riesz representation theorem in the setting of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian has explained you, it is rather easy.

Here, I would like to give you the same "feeling of easiness" using the classical form of a bilinear map once a basis has been fixed, i.e.,

$$B(X,Y)=X^TAY \tag{1}$$

(see example below) where the vectors $x,y$ are assimilated to the column vectors $X,Y$ of their coordinates with respect to a fixed basis. Using (1), one can write:

$$B(X,Y)=X^TAY=X^TA^TY=(AX)^TY=(AX)\cdot Y \tag{2}$$

(assuming  matrix $A$ is symmetrical) where symbol $\cdot$ is for dot product.

(2) is nothing else that the coordinate form of your expression $A(X)(Y)$.

Example of a bilinear map under the coordinate form (1):

$$2x^2+10xy+3z^2=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x&y\end{pmatrix}}_{X^T}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}2&5\\5&3\end{pmatrix}}_A\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}}_X.$$

Comment: Thanks! By "vectors , are assimilated to the column vectors ," do you mean $X = [x^\intercal, ..., x^\intercal]$, and then $B(x, y) = X^\intercal Ay$?

Comment: I don't understand your notation $[x^\intercal, ..., x^\intercal]$. I just say for example in $\mathbb{R^2}$, that, if a basis $(u_1,u_2)$ is fixed and a vector $x$ is written $x=a_1u_1+a_2u_2$, I assimilate $x$ with column vector $\binom{a_1}{a_2}$.